# Where will the energy go into when the block is at rest in the presence of friction?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, friction

Suppose a block is being accelerated on a horizontal plane by a machine in the presence of friction. The machine will burn fuel and generate energy which will be used in accelerating the block and part of the energy will be used aginst friction which will turn to heat.

But if the block initially at rest and then the machine exerts a force equal to the frictional force, then the block will be at rest. But the machine will still burn fuel and generate energy. Where will this energy go into?

Comment: A "machine" does not _have_ to burn fuel in order to maintain a constant force on a non-moving object. For example, a simple spring can do that, and a spring does not use any fuel at all.

Comment: @Solomon Slow Yeah. This can also be a case. Gravity can also work like this without doing any work. But I'm interested in the cases where there is a machine which is burning fuel.

Comment: So,... if the machine is burning fuel, not doing work on any external thing, not storing potential energy internally, then all of the heat released by burning the fuel must be going to waste. Your own muscles do exactly that when you push against something that moves. While you exert a "steady" force on some un-moving object, each fiber in your muscle cells is continually contracting and relaxing--using energy for each cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like the same question as I am pushing the wall but the wall doesn't move, but I'm tired after some time. I am losing energy but I can't see any work output.
Now coming to your question, the energy is still converting into heat inside the machine itself.

Comment: Kumar So the machine will overheat itself?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 0):

The machine hits the block. By virtue of Newton's third law block reacts to the machine. If rest the friction of the machine less than that of block it will move back and stop for a while. Then it will gain velocity and hits the block again. Energy is lost for heating the block and machine during collisions.

Comment: Why does the machine has to have a collision with the block? We could just stick a rocket will the block and then turn it on. So no collision happens.

Comment: The block pushes the machine back if they were stuck at the beginning.

Comment: How does this solve anything? Can you elaborate please?